# How to run Zephyr Echo Client-Server sample using nrf52840dk & nrf52840dongle?

Tags: iot, contiki, zephyr-rtos, nrf52, nrf52840

I'm trying to run the Echo Client and Echo Server example of Zephyr.
I want to use nrf5284dk as server and nrf5284dongle as client (or vice versa).
I should also mention that my OS is Windows 11.

First I build and flashed the server to the dk.

```
west build -p -b nrf52840dk_nrf52840 -d build_dk_echo_server \zephyr\samples\net\sockets\echo_server\ -- -DCONF_FILE="prj.conf"
west flash -d .\build_dk_echo_server\
```

Then I tried to build and flash the client to the dongle.

```
west build -p -b nrf52840dongle_nrf52840 .\zephyr\samples\net\sockets\echo_client -- -DCONF_FILE="prj.conf" 
nrfutil pkg generate --hw-version 52 --sd-req=0x00 --application build/zephyr/zephyr.hex --application-version 1 echo_client_dongle.zip
nrfutil dfu usb-serial -pkg echo_client_dongle.zip -p COM11
```

But i get the error:

```
[00:00:00.321,746] <err> net_if: There is no network interface to work with!
*** Booting Zephyr OS build zephyr-v3.5.0-4086-g0a8d03b95f84 ***
[00:00:00.322,113] <wrn> net_config: No auto-started network interface - network-bound app initialization skipped.
[00:00:00.322,113] <inf> net_echo_client_sample: Run echo client
[00:00:00.322,174] <inf> net_echo_client_sample: Network disconnected
```

I am quite new at this (I don't have any previous experience with programming IoT devices).
I do not even know if trying to run these samples in these devices is valid.
Do I need to enable anything? What steps should I follow?
Any information/guidance could help.

Thank you

Comment: I think it depends where you are trying to end up with this setup; ie, what application are you ultimately trying to build using what protocols. nrf52840 is primarily a Bluetooth device (can't remember if it only supports LE or both full and LE) device but can also do IEEE 802.15.4. Echo examples you have require some kind of network interface to run; and while both of the above protocols can be used to provide networking interfaces, Bluetooth at least typically isn't used in that way. If you do want networking to work, there's a fair bit of additional setup needed I think.